# MapMvcAttributeRoutes using optional id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I am using `MapMvcAttributeRoutes` and would like to have an optional id, but I don't know the proper syntax. Help would be appreciated

I am trying something as:

```
 // GET: Statistikk/Meg
[Route("Statistikk/Meg/{id:regex(UrlParameter.Optional)}")]
public ActionResult MegIndex()
{
    return View("Meg/Index");
}
```

Custom Route I am replicating

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "StatistikkMeg",
            "Statistikk/Meg/{id}",
            new { controller = "Statistikk", action = "MegIndex", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: can't you use nullable on your id?

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I am following a course and nothing about my problem was mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with making the id nullable

```
    [Route("Statistikk/Meg/{id?}")]
```

More info at https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/